# AngularJS iterating through Eventbrite events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, eventbrite

My Json file is [here.](https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?q=Paris&token=KUWBRV7DYYQS7FD7W7RF)
My HomeController is:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
   events.then(function(data) {
    $scope.events = data;
  });
   $scope.test="success";
}]);
```

and my html file is:

```
<a href="#/">Home</a>
<h1>  {{test}}  </h1>
<section class="container" ng-repeat="event in events">

<div class="col-sm-4" >
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" />
        <div class="block">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{event.events[0].name.text}}</h4>
          <p class="card-text">{{event}}</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</section>
<h1>{{test}}</h1>
```

My problem occurs when I am trying to loop over "events" array in the JSON file.
I have tried to write "$scope.events = data.events;" in Home controller, " ng-repeat="event in events.events"" or "ng-repeat="event in events[0]"" in html file. This breaks loop and nothing is shown, but if I use "ng-repeat="event in events"" and then variable {{event.events[0].name.text}} in the code later on, it all works fine. I don't understand why there is a problem. It should work fine from my previous experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare in your controller

`$scope.events = data.data.events;`

and have such template:

```
<section class="container" ng-repeat="event in events">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" />
      <div class="block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{event.name.text}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">{{event}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

it should work. See codepen [here](http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/ZeoZQv?editors=1010)

Comment: $scope.events = data.events; crashes controller. Can it be because I am using: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>?

Comment: By crashes I mean that it doesn't show anything from the home.html loop

Comment: Hard to say...maybe you can prepare a fiddle so we can have a look

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by fiddle?

Comment: Providing a whole working example of your code where the error could be reproduced; you can use tools as jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: Well, controller doesn't look to work now at all: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=HTmxx7mVgx

Comment: You have a syntax error on the first line, should be ```var app = angular.module("EventsApp", []);```. Besides you are not importing angularjs script..

Comment: because it doesn't allow to have <head> tag

Comment: Have a look at this: http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/ZeoZQv?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks. I think your code clearly shows that application doesn't return anything if .events is added

Comment: I updated the fiddle; if ```data``` is the response of an ajax calls then you need to have  ```$scope.events = data.data.events;``` in your controller or alternatively ```return data.data;``` in your success callback. Basically the data itself, it's inside ```data``` property of the response object.

Comment: it is still very strange form me and I don't understand why this happened, but it worked. Would you like to write an answer that I could accept?

Comment: You can accept my answer which is linked to the updated codepen